Why are the books in Mr. Queen blurred?
In the first episode and a couple of times later, the pages of the book are blurred.
Why are the pages blurred - and if they need to be blurred, why use them in the first place?
I can only imagine that it's Joseon-era porn, or illustrations of fighting techniques, and that censorship is Korea is strong. But then, why did the producers add the book knowing it would have to be blurred, especially when it doesn't add anything to the plot?



Usually, with old ink on old paper, time makes the ink to smudge (not sure about the proper word here?). How old are these books supposed to be?

Well Joseon era is around 1400-1800, but for them, I guess are new because is a historic drama. But those blur are add it post edit.

This is only partial, so I'm not posting it as a full answer, but regarding "why include the book if it's going to be censored" - this is nothing new. Many creatives are willing to gamble on the chances that they'll be able to sneak the objectionable content past the censors somehow - a famous example being The Simpsons Movie showing Bart's genitals on-screen for several seconds and still only getting relatively low age ratings.

Censorship in South Korea is pretty strict and Korean TV stations particularly target and censor automatically 4 major elements: weapons, cigarettes, tattoos and brands.
Large swords in ancient dramas aren’t blurred, but small knives that are intended to be used as weapons in certain scenes are blurred out. The Korea Communications Standards Commission (a government agency that regulates TV, radio, and the Internet within South Korea) has issued a censor for anything that might cause excessive shock, anxiety or disgust to viewers.
So perhaps the book depicts fighting techniques that might be considered too violent according to the Korea Communications Standards Commission.
Producers will add many items knowing it will be censored later on. I don't read korean or watch this drama, but perhaps the book was visually interesting or had something that added to the realism of the scene and the production just decided to include it.

"Producers will add many items knowing it will be censored later on." I'm just curious, is this actually true? Instead of avoiding anything for which they are confident it will be censored, they add them anyway? There's no chance that controversies emerged later and the censoring was added in post-production out of an abundance of caution?

@uhoh "...controversy has surrounded a line in episode 2 in which a character referred to The Annals of the Joseon Dynasty as 'merely jirashi.'" So not the book itself but what a character said about it. Unless you know more, that's all I could find https://www.koreaboo.com/news/mr-queen-mocking-korean-history/
